# xlsxwriter and pandas for reporting

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

I am trying to create a basic excel report.

I am trying display a dataframe as well as some custom text/titles, not part of the dataframe.

However, I can only get one or the other. I don't really understand the end of the code that is needed for the dataframe to appear (`workbook = writer.book` and `worksheet = writer.sheets['Reports']`.

Here is my code:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('reportTemplate.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('reportTemplate.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Reports')

# REPORT TITLE
worksheet.write('D2','Daily In-Store Report')

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('reportTemplate.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Reports')
worksheet.write('D2','Daily In-Store Report')

reportTimes = ['Day','Week','Period','Quarter','Year']
cityList = ['ontario','bayshore','ottawa','limeridge','oshawa','scarborough','sherway','massonville','gatineau',
            'quebec','anjou','dix30','Fairview','laval','mtltrust','stbruno','gcapitale','stefoy','rivieres','chicoutimi','sherbrooke','canada']

# LOOP THROUGH FILES
rowNb = 4
for time in reportTimes:
    # TITLE
    tableTitle = time + ' report as of ...'
    worksheet.write('A'+str(rowNb),tableTitle)
    rowNb += 1

    headRow, secondHead = createHeadings(time)
    worksheet.write_row('B' + str(rowNb), headRow)  
    worksheet.write_row('B' + str(rowNb), secondHead)
    rowNb += 2

    df = pd.read_csv('fy_' + time.lower() + '.csv')
    df.set_index('legacy_id',inplace=True)
    df = df.reindex(cityList)
    print(df)

    df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='Reports',startrow = rowNb,header=False)

    workbook  = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets['Reports']

    writer.save()
```

As the code is right now, it only displays the dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to me whether you're trying to write multiple sheets in one Excel file. If so, the problem may be that you're re-writing the same sheet called 'Reports' four times. Also, here are some basics to try. Put the `df.to_excel()` after `pd.ExcelWriter()`. Then remove from the `for` loop the last four lines. Finally, put `writer.save()` after the `for` loop ends. (This was not very clear for me when I first learned them, too. See more examples at [this link](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html).)

Edit: here's fully executing code (with stub data). One of of the keys was to enable multiple writes to the worksheet using `writer.sheets['Reports'] = worksheet` - see [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32957441/putting-many-python-pandas-dataframes-to-one-excel-worksheet).

```
dummy_df = pd.DataFrame([[10,np.NaN],[12,42],[16,np.NaN],[20,3],[25,16],[30,1],[40,19],[60,99]],columns=['legacy_id', 'b'])
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('reportTemplate.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
workbook = writer.book
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Reports')
writer.sheets['Reports'] = worksheet # enable multiple writes to sheet

# REPORT TITLE
worksheet.write('D2','Daily In-Store Report')

reportTimes = ['Day','Week','Period','Quarter','Year']
cityList = ['ontario','bayshore','ottawa','limeridge','oshawa','scarborough','sherway','massonville','gatineau',
            'quebec','anjou','dix30','Fairview','laval','mtltrust','stbruno','gcapitale','stefoy','rivieres','chicoutimi','sherbrooke','canada']

# LOOP THROUGH FILES
rowNb = 4
for time in reportTimes:
    # TITLE
    tableTitle = time + ' report as of ...'
    worksheet.write('A'+str(rowNb),tableTitle)
    rowNb += 1

    headRow, secondHead = "dummy head row", "dummy second head" #I don't have your createHeadings(time)
    worksheet.write_row('B' + str(rowNb), headRow)  
    worksheet.write_row('B' + str(rowNb), secondHead)
    rowNb += 2

    df = dummy_df.copy(deep=True) # pd.read_csv('fy_' + time.lower() + '.csv')
    df.set_index('legacy_id',inplace=True)
    df = df.reindex(cityList)
    #print(df)
    df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='Reports', startrow = rowNb)
    rowNb += df.shape[0] #gives row count

writer.save()
```

Comment: I am trying to display 4 dataframes as well as some basic titles on top of each of them. I am having trouble with adding the text as it does not show up.

Comment: All in the same sheet?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the confusion

Comment: I edited and tested your loop. Try this version out - replace the stubs with your actual data.

Comment: @VincFort, did this work for you? Please mark this as answered if so. Let me know.