# How to download html table content?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I want to download financial data ("konsernregnskap" not "morregnskap") from the following website, but I am not sure how to get all content downloaded: https://www.proff.no/regnskap/yara-international-asa/oslo/hovedkontortjenester/IGB6AV410NZ/

Tried to locate the tables with xpath but I have been unsuccessful.

I want to download all content into one excel sheet.

Comment: You need to check `//div[@id="keyFigures_corporateAccounts"]` for the data you need.

Comment: Please include your code when seeking debugging help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer given by @rusu_ro1 is correct. However, I think that [*Pandas*](https://pandas.pydata.org/) is the right tool for job here.

You can use [*pandas.read_html*](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.read_html.html) to get  all the tables in the page. Then use  *[pandas.DataFrame.to_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html)* to write only the last 4 tables to the excel workbook.

The following script scrapes the data and writes each table to a different sheet.

```
import pandas as pd
all_tables = pd.read_html(
    "https://www.proff.no/regnskap/yara-international-asa/oslo/hovedkontortjenester/IGB6AV410NZ/"
)
with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx') as writer:
    # Last 4 tables has the 'konsernregnskap' data
    for idx, df in enumerate(all_tables[4:8]):
        # Remove last column (empty)
        df = df.drop(df.columns[-1], axis=1)
        df.to_excel(writer, "Table {}".format(idx))
```

**Notes:**

- You can also *[write all the DataFrames to a single sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32957441/putting-many-python-pandas-dataframes-to-one-excel-worksheet)*.
- Ensure that *lxml* library is installed. `pip install lxml`

> flavor : str or None, container of strings
>
> The parsing engine to use. ‘bs4’ and ‘html5lib’ are synonymous with
>   each other, they are both there for backwards compatibility. The
>   default of None tries to use lxml to parse and if that fails it falls
>   back on bs4 + html5lib.

From  [*HTML Table Parsing Gotchas*](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/io.html#io-html-gotchas)

> html5lib generates valid HTML5 markup from invalid markup
>   automatically. This is extremely important for parsing HTML tables,
>   since it guarantees a valid document. However, that does NOT mean that
>   it is “correct”, since the process of fixing markup does not have a
>   single definition.

In your specific case it drops the 5th table (it returns only 7). Perhaps b'coz both 1st and 5th table has the same data.

Answer (score 1):

you have 8 tables within class table-wrap, first 4 tables belong to "morregnskap" tab and the next 4 tables belong to "konsernregnskap" tab, so by choosing the last 4 you are choosing your desired tables from where you can start to scrape your data

```
import requests
import json
import bs4

url = 'https://www.proff.no/regnskap/yara-international-asa/oslo/hovedkontortjenester/IGB6AV410NZ/'


response = requests.get(url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
tables = soup.find_all('div', {'table-wrap'})


konsernregnskap_data = tables[5:]
```