# Multiple DataFrame to Excel

Tags: python, dataframe

How can I export multiple dataframe to an one Excell sheet. I have 2 dataframes. Sometimes it can be more than 2 dataframes.

```
cars = {'name': ['Audi','VW'],
    'modell': ["A4","Golf"]
    }

cars2 = {'name': ['BMW','MB'],
    'modell': ["3er","e-class"]
    }

df = pd.DataFrame(cars, columns= ['name', 'modell'])
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_simple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32957441/putting-many-python-pandas-dataframes-to-one-excel-worksheet

Comment: Do you want to write each dataframe in a different sheet or in the same sheet?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not about writing to excel (this you know how to do) is about concatenating dataframes, you can use [pandas.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) for that end.

In this example I create two sheets one with the datasets concatenated vertically, and the other with the datasets concatenated horizontally, as a bonus you know how to save multiple sheets to the same file.

```py
cars = {'name': ['Audi','VW'],
    'modell': ["A4","Golf"]
    }

cars2 = {'name': ['BMW','MB'],
    'modell': ["3er","e-class"]
    }
## assuming that all your dataframes have the same set of columns
dataFrames = [pd.DataFrame(d) for d in [cars, cars2]]
with pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_simple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
  vertical = pd.concat(dataFrames, axis=0) # if the dataframes have the same columns
  horizontal = pd.concat(dataFrames, axis=1) # if the dataframes have the same indices
  
  vertical.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Vertically')
  horizontal.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Horizontally')
```

Comment: But I only want one sheet

Comment: Sorry, I will update it

Answer (score 1):

Where do you want the dataframes to go?

This code will place them side by side on the same worksheet.

```
import pandas as pd

cars1 = {'name': ['Audi','VW'],
    'modell': ["A4","Golf"]
    }

cars2 = {'name': ['BMW','MB'],
    'modell': ["3er","e-class"]
    }
all_cars = [cars1, cars2]

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_simple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
startcol = 0

for car in all_cars:
  df = pd.DataFrame(car, columns= ['name', 'modell'])
  df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startcol=startcol, index=None)
  startcol += len(df.columns)
writer.save()
```

Comment: They should be listed one below the other. Did you know how I can do this?

Comment: You can use startrow instead of startcol if you want them to be shown in that way.