# How to format and write excel using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, excel

Lets assume that we have nested python dictionaries which should be written in single excel sheet file.

Following are sample dictionaries which can be used.

```
Car = [
    {
        "carbmodel": "Model A",
        "attributes": {
            "make": "Brand X",
            "year": 2023,
            "color": "Red",
            "engine": "V6",
            "transmission": "Automatic",
            "features": ["GPS", "Bluetooth", "Leather Seats"]
        }
    },
    {
        "carbmodel": "Model B",
        "attributes": {
            "make": "Brand Y",
            "year": 2022,
            "color": "Blue",
            "engine": "Inline-4",
            "transmission": "Manual",
            "features": ["Sunroof", "Backup Camera", "Alloy Wheels"]
        }
    },
    {
        "carbmodel": "Model C",
        "attributes": {
            "make": "Brand Z",
            "year": 2023,
            "color": "Black",
            "engine": "V8",
            "transmission": "Automatic",
            "features": ["Apple CarPlay", "Heated Seats", "Navigation"]
        }
    }
]
```

```
bikes = [
    {
        "carbmodel": "Bike X",
        "attributes": {
            "make": "Brand P",
            "year": 2023,
            "color": "Green",
            "engine": "250cc",
            "transmission": "Manual",
            "features": ["ABS", "LED Lights", "Digital Display"]
        }
    },
    {
        "carbmodel": "Bike Y",
        "attributes": {
            "make": "Brand Q",
            "year": 2022,
            "color": "Orange",
            "engine": "200cc",
            "transmission": "Manual",
            "features": ["Disc Brakes", "Tubeless Tires", "Kick Start"]
        }
    },
    {
        "carbmodel": "Bike Z",
        "attributes": {
            "make": "Brand R",
            "year": 2023,
            "color": "Black",
            "engine": "300cc",
            "transmission": "Manual",
            "features": ["Fuel Injection", "Mono Suspension", "Dual Exhaust"]
        }
    }
]
```

This should be written in excel file using pandas dataframe in following format which is shown in screenshot.[image]

Really appreciate any help, thank you in advance.

This is used code block for testing the scenario.

```
import xlsxwriter

# Create a new Excel file
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('merged_cells_and_data.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Add some content to the merged cells
cell_format = workbook.add_format({
    'bold': True,
    'align': 'center',
    'valign': 'vcenter',
    'bg_color': 'yellow'
})

worksheet.merge_range('A1:E1', 'Merged Cells Example', cell_format)

# Nested dictionary
useful_info = {
    'personal_info': {
        'name': 'John Doe',
        'age': 30,
        'location': 'New York, USA'
    },
    'contact_info': {
        'email': 'johndoe@example.com',
        'phone': '123-456-7890'
    },
    'employment': {
        'company': 'ABC Corporation',
        'position': 'Software Engineer',
        'years_experience': 5
    },
    'skills': ['Python', 'JavaScript', 'SQL', 'Problem Solving'],
    'education': {
        'university': 'University of XYZ',
        'degree': 'Bachelor of Science in Computer Science',
        'graduation_year': 2018
    }
}

# Write nested dictionary starting from the 2nd row
row = 1
for key, value in useful_info.items():
    worksheet.write(row, 0, key)
    if isinstance(value, dict):
        for inner_key, inner_value in value.items():
            worksheet.write(row, 1, inner_key)
            worksheet.write(row, 2, inner_value)
            row += 1
    else:
        worksheet.write(row, 1, value)
    row += 1

# Close the workbook
workbook.close()

print("Excel file with merged cells and nested dictionary data created successfully.")
```

```
#Merge Cell issue with Multiple pandas #dataframe created from nested dictionaries 
mport xlsxwriter

Nested json added to dataframe

f1 = pd.DataFrame(sample_1).T 12= pd.DataFrame(sample_2).T

rint(df1.shape[0])

rint(df1.shape[1])

ef multiple_dfs(df_list, sheets, file_name, spaces): writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_name, engine='xlsxwriter') # Create an new Excel file and add a worksheet. workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook("merge1.xlsx") worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet("Validation")

# Increase the cell size of the merged cells to highlight the formatting.

worksheet.set_column("A:E", 12)

worksheet.set_row(3, 30)

worksheet.set_row(6, 30)

worksheet.set_row(7, 30)
# Create a format to use in the merged range. merge_format = workbook.add_format(

"bold": 1,

"border": 1,

"align":"center",

"valign": "vcenter",

"fg_color": "yellow".

}

# Merge 3 cells.

worksheet.merge_range("A1:E1", "Merged Range", merge_format) # Create a format to use in the merged range.

workbook.close()

with pd.ExcelWriter(file_name) as writer:

  row = 3

  for dataframe in df_list:

    dataframe.to_excel (writer,sheet_name=sheets, startrow row, startcol=0)

   row row + len(dataframe.index) + spaces + 1

    #writer.close()

    #workbook.close()

dfs = [df1, df2]

## run function

multiple_dfs(dfs, 'Validation', 'merge1.xlsx', 2)
```

Comment: What did you try so far and why didn't it work? Also, does this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32957441/putting-many-python-pandas-dataframes-to-one-excel-worksheet) answer your problem?

Comment: @SurajShourie Tried this before but not able to merge the cell properly. In attempted trial cell got merged but failed to write that in required format.

Comment: Please give the code that is working partially/not working.

Comment: @Sid updated the description with tried code block

Answer (score 1):

The only missing part of your test code is converting list to string before writing to Excel.

```
# Write nested dictionary starting from the 2nd row
row = 1
for key, value in useful_info.items():
    worksheet.write(row, 0, key)
    if isinstance(value, dict):
        for inner_key, inner_value in value.items():
            worksheet.write(row, 1, inner_key)
            worksheet.write(row, 2, inner_value)
            row += 1
    else:
        if isinstance(value, list):
            value = ', '.join(value)
        worksheet.write(row, 1, value)
    row += 1
```

Writing data to Excel with Pandas is similar to using XlsxWriter. Here is a sample snippet:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [1, 2, 3],
                   'Total': [4, 5, 6]}) 
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r'd:/temp/output.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter') 
# Convert index to column if needed
df.reset_index().to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)  
# Access the XlsxWriter workbook and sheet
workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
# Add formatting - merge, font, border
style = {'bold': True, 'font_color': 'blue', 'font_size': 18, 'font_name': 'Arial' }
worksheet.merge_range('A1:B1', 'Report', workbook.add_format(style))
writer.close()
```

Comment: Thank you.  There was one more drawback with previously tried code, if tried to write multiple dataframes, and tried to merge cell upto length of column separately for each dataframe (just like shown in description screenshot), then it was giving cell merge overlapping issue.

Comment: Please include the code in OP and show the detail of `cell merge overlapping issue`.

Comment: @tallerExcelHome updated the tried code block. But it is failure scenario where merge cell failed. I tried to reproduce overlap issue but not able to.