# Insert different data in a specific range in an excel sheet with Openpyxl

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I need to insert data in a range of a spreadsheet with Openpyxl.
The data comes from a list containing data extracted from a json file.
I want for example to insert the data in a range of "A10:K35". In that range insert the values belonging to "Product_ID" from "A10:A35" and "Code_Subgroup" data into "B10:B35" etc ....
How could I do this?

```
import _read_json as rj

parameter = ["Product_ID", "Code_Subgroup", "Stock", "Serial", "Description", "AC", "DC"]

data_to_insert = rj.get_value_parameters(parameter)

def add_data_sheet(rango, sheet, data):
    
    cell_range = sheet[rango]
    
    for cell in cell_range:

        j += 1
        cell[0].value = data[j]
```

This is the code I use to insert the data, but I must specify the range like "A10:A35" and the parameter. I have tried several ways to loop through it but I can't do it!!!

I have tried several loops to traverse the list of lists 'data_to_insert'. But my attempts only get errors like:
'Cannot convert [...] to excel' or that the value is outside the index.

Comment: Generally it would make sense to read and convert your data from json to a dataframe then write the dataframe to Excel given that writing the values using Openpyxl is cell by cell. Unless you are using 'append' which might be the what you are attempting given the reference to list of lists. If you do have a list of list then you'll need to loop and write each list using append. Dataframe is probably still the better option. However cannot comment further with the limited detail.

Comment: This post [how-to-format-and-write-excel-using-pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76893517/how-to-format-and-write-excel-using-pandas) might help

Comment: What is `data[j]`?  I suspect it is a series of values, in which case you probably want to use `zip()` to allow you to iterate in parallel over two series. It would be helpful if you including some sample data.